# What data structure does String Pool in java uses internally?

Tags: java, string-pool

I understand the use cases of String Pool in java, but I am wondering what data structure is used while implementing String Pool.
I mean when we talk about interning of strings, JVM needs to search the entire String Pool for any existing String. So how does this process is optimized?

Comment: String pool is just like a cache of strings using flyweight design pattern.. I think array would work just fine.

Comment: @ShanuGupta But won't it will have a huge impact on time complexity? I mean searching an array for a string literal is too expensive.